Geometric interpretation of eigenvalues with positive real part
For any real square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, we say that $A$ is positive-stable if all its eigenvalues have positive real part, and positive-definite (abusing terminology) if its symmetric part $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is positive-definite, or equivalently, $x^T A x > 0$ for all non-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
My geometric interpretation of the latter property is that $A$ does not 'reflect' any vector $x$, in the sense that the angle between $x$ and $Ax$ is always in $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. I'm trying to find a geometric interpretation for the former property. It was shown in this question that $A$ is positive-stable iff there exists $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is positive-definite, which means that positive-stable matrices are exactly those which do not 'reflect' any vector $x$ for some change of coordinates induced by $P$... But I can't quite wrap my head around what this means, or why eigenvalues with positive real part induce this property (intuitively)?
Question: Is there a simpler geometric interpretation of positive stability, perhaps with respect to the generalized eigenbasis of $A$ rather than with respect to some change of basis?

Not a full answer, but a thought that may help your intuition when using the Eigenbasis: for $z$ a complex number, multiplication by $z$ is equivalent to scaling the plane by $|z|$, and rotating it by $arg(z)$. If $\text{Re}(z)$ is positive, then $arg(z) \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. So each Eigenvector is being rotated by an acute angle.

@BrandonduPreez Thanks for your answer. The part I'm struggling with is that
does not typically have an eigenbasis, so I'm struggling to interpret the more general geometric interpretation, for eg with respect to generalized eigenbasis. Consider for example the shear transformation $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.
